# unable to register flash10c.ocx

Tags: deployment, vb6

When I use Package and Deployment Wizard to make an installer of my vb6 application. When I test it and installed it, upon reaching 100% installation, it was unable to register Flash10c.ocx. I tried to ignore it and try to run the installed application. The application runs but the flash movie does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this at **Run** dialog:

```
regsvr32 Flash10c.ocx
```

But first put the `Flash10c.ocx` file in **system32** folder.

Comment: I got this message. "The module 'Flash10c.ocx' module was loaded but the call to DllRegisterServer failed with error code 0x80070005."

Comment: @gibz357: looks like your flash10c file is corrupted or there is some other windows problem. try to restart your pc and then c.

Comment: i think i have a corrupted flash10c.ocx. i tried to install in on another OS. it still have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

The OCX quite likely relies on some other DLLs or registry keys in order to work, just copying it is unlikely to work.

I think it's distributed with Windows now, in which case you are not supposed to include it with your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to force the user to install the Internet Explorer version of flash (note: installing in Firefox, Chrome or Safari will not work as they do not use the OCX version of flash).  Not easy to do in the Package and Deployment wizard, but pretty simple in an real installer (if you need instructions for Inno Setup, I can help with that).  Otherwise you can write a quick check in the beginning of your VB file to make sure the OCX is registered, and fail if it isn't.

If you really want to distribute the flash ocx, you have license flash player (usually free), you can [apply to Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/products/players/fpsh_distribution1.html) to receive a redistributable package.